# Calling and gathering results from py.test from within code

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm working on a system that needs to be able to test python files with py.test, and use the output (what tests passed and failed) within the program. Is there anyway to call py.test from within python, tell it to run the testing code in [name].py on the code in [otherName].py, and have it return the results of the test?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [Calling pytest from Python code](http://pytest.org/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code) at [Usage and Invocations](http://pytest.org/latest/usage.html) page.

Also limiting tests to the specific file could be done by [Specifying tests / selecting tests](http://pytest.org/latest/usage.html#specifying-tests-selecting-tests).

In other words, this should do the trick:

```
pytest.main(['my_test_file.py'])
```

P.S.: [Py.test Documantation](http://pytest.org/latest/contents.html) is pretty good, you can find most of the answers there ;).

Comment: If you need to get more detailed machine-parseable info you might want or need to write a little plugin and pass it to the pytest.main() call as second argument.  For example you could implement a "pytest_unconfigure(config)" hook function and then call ``config.getplugin("terminalreporter") and access its ``stats`` attribute - a dictionary mapping test outcomes to test reports.